# PayPal Payment Using Wordpress Bitnami Site on AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, paypal, bitnami

I have an issue with PayPal payments.
My site runs on AWS, I have used Bitnami to install Wordpress. In addition, I installed a Wordpress theme

**Question**: Theme developer says that the issue is with the server, because they tested their own credentials on my site. Their credentials do NOT work on my site, but they work on theirs. I have basic package from AWS without the support. Is the issue with AWS, PayPal or Wordpress theme? Can you please help me with resolving this issue with concreate instructions? I ran out of ideas...

Here are the infos seen on PayPal's API calls (*ID's, IPs and site names have been altered for security reasons*)

**Metadata from Paypal:**

```
{
  "create_time": "2022-11-04T14:05:26Z",
  "correlation_id": "f85s4eba548fd5",
  "tag_id": [],
  "client_id": "AUd59ob1CTWI9eoNgojKMNeXmdZa2sFu2DtNaojjmuOhECNWzQwjldAWrsoRvhLbyTBpLQo86EtnIhnUs",
  "account_number": "1294920421777245576",
  "http_status": 400,
  "url": "/v1/payments/payment"
}
```

**PayPal Request:**

```
{
  "additional_properties": "xxxxxx",
  "body": {
    "experience_profile_id": "XP-XBUK-SGDC-PKH3-4ZFW",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
      "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
      "cancel_url": "https://www.[my-site-domain]/dashboard-property-list/",
      "return_url": "https://www.[my-site-domain]/paypal-processor/"
    },
    "transactions": [
      {
        "amount": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "details": {
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "subtotal": "150.00",
            "tax": "0.00"
          },
          "total": "150.00"
        },
        "description": "Listing payment on https://www.[my-site-domain]/",
        "item_list": {
          "items": [
            {
              "currency": "USD",
              "name": "Listing Payment",
              "price": "150.00",
              "quantity": "1",
              "sku": "Paid Listing"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "header": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "deflate, gzip, br",
    "akamai-x-forwarded-for-7": "xxxxxx",
    "authorization": "xxxxx",
    "client-auth": "xxxxx",
    "client_info": "xxxxxx",
    "content-length": "554",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "correlation-id": "f852eba5r8fd5",
    "edge-locator": "xxxxxx",
    "edgeid": "xxxxxx",
    "host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
    "paypal-routing-metadata": "xxxxxx",
    "pp_client_ssl_cipher": "TLS_AES_254_GCM_SHA284",
    "pp_client_ssl_protocol": "TLSv1.3",
    "pp_geo_loc": "DE",
    "pp_remote_addr": "[my-ip]",
    "pp_vip": "[pp_vip]",
    "referer": "xxxxxx",
    "user-agent": "WordPress/6.0.3; https://www.[my-site-domain].me",
    "x-forwarded-for": "[some-ip]",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "xxxxxx",
    "x-paypal-correlation-id": "f254efa548fd5",
    "x-pp-corrid": "f854eca538dd5",
    "x-pp-idempotencyid": "f852ebs548fd5_1647572726",
    "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp": "apiplatformproxyserv",
    "x-sigsci-agentresponse": "xxxxxx",
    "x-sigsci-mac": "xxxxxx",
    "x-sigsci-requestid": "xxxxxx",
    "x-slr-orig-script_uri": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"
  },
  "method": "POST"
}
```

**PayPal Response:**

```
{
  "additional_properties": "xxxxxx",
  "body": {
    "debug_id": "f854dba538fd1",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#error-INVALID_EXPERIENCE_PROFILE_ID",
    "message": "The requested experience profile ID was not found",
    "name": "INVALID_EXPERIENCE_PROFILE_ID"
  },
  "duration_time": "xxxxxx",
  "header": {
    "APPLICATION_ID": "APP-80W282125P529543T",
    "BORDER-IP": "xxxxxx",
    "CALLER_ACCT_NUM": "AS2PUCKGHDHDJ",
    "Date": "Fri, 04 Nov 2022 14:05:27 GMT",
    "SERVER_INFO": "xxxxxx",
    "paypal-debug-id": "f854abf543fd5"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**UPDATE 12-NOV-2022:**
I have used another server with the same Wordpress theme and same PayPal setup to test the payment, and it worked. It sent 200 and 201 messages.
Then I switched back to my site on AWS and Bitnami, and it is returning 400 message. When I click on "Pay with PayPal" the site only refreshes, it does not connect to PayPal and it does not give me login form...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is straightforward, XP-XBUK-SGDC-PKH3-4ZFW is not a valid experience profile ID for the credentials you are calling with

Whatever your Wordpress plugin is doing, it needs to change to specify (in its API request) an experience profile ID created (also via API) with the credentials you are testing with.

Current PayPal Checkout integrations use v2/checkout/orders rather than the old v1/payments, and do not make use of experience profile IDs.

Comment: I have tested my paypal setup on another site with the same Wordpress theme and it works. Based on this it seems to me that the issue is either with AWS or Bitnami. Do you perhaps have any idea how I can get this to work? For example, are there any settings I need to adjust on AWS or Bitnami side, so that the payment with PayPal works? Currently, when I click on Pay with PayPal, the site only refreshes... I have added the screenshot of 200 and 201 messages from the test site, 400 message comes from my site (see original question above please)

Comment: use a valid experience_profile_id