# PayPal poiting to a non-existing sandbox account/profile

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

in the following I will describe the context: On developer.paypal.com website (My apps and credentials) with my personal account I created a new application.
Then I created a webhook and added to it access to all functions.
In the final step I've integrated PP app with my website.

The problem is that when I try to make a purchase with PayPal and when I am redirected to a PayPal page I see PayPal profile/sandbox account which I cannot find in PayPal console. It seems it is some older profile I've created with that name, but it's not visible in the console.

I've also tried to create a new app and new webhook, but the issue is the same.

Can anyone please help? Does anyone have an idea what to do, where to search?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: "In the final step I've integrated PP app with my website." -- elaborate, in detail

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX, I'm using purchased Wordpress theme in which I simply added Client ID and Secret ID in the backend. That's all maneuver I have disposable. 
On PayPal side in the backend I'm getting 400 error message. 
The topic is related with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366767/paypal-payment-using-wordpress-bitnami-site-on-aws/74367296?noredirect=1#comment131366872_74367296

Comment: In addition, this time I am using a different (business) account. The previous PP account was personal. The theme's developer keeps saying that the issue is with AWS/Bitnami. I find it hard to believe that I am the first one getting this error using AWS/Bitnami... Could you recommend any checks/tests to get more clarity? Thanks!

Comment: If your system is correctly configured to use a sandbox client ID and secret, then the checkout page should open to send payments to the corresponding sandbox business account that the sandbox app was created for. There aren't any other possible scenarios, unless your system is configured differently.